# Removing the validation when Redux-Form Field is disabled

Tags: redux-form

I am using Redux form v6.5.0 and having a requirement of 
**Removing the validation for any Field when the disabled props is passed as true**.

I wrote a custom logic to disable the validation inside render() of custom field component, but looks like **updateSyncErrors()** is not getting called on the form even after updating the values manually. Because of this, **syncErrors object** is persisting the field validation error.

```
    if (field.disabled) {
        field.meta.invalid = false;
        field.meta.error = undefined;
        field.meta.valid = true;
    }
```

Can we have some straight forward - simple & better approach which tackles this requirement and fixes this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation, I wanted to disable or enable fields based on API response and according to that, I had to enable and disable validations also. I was able to do that in the below way

> Input Field (select field)

```
              <Field
                formItemLayout={layout}
                name="configType"
                validate={
                  !(
                    response &&
                    response.data &&
                    response.data.isEnabled
                  )
                    ? [required]
                    : undefined
                }
                component={ASelectField}
                placeholder="configType"
                disabled={
                    response &&
                    response.data &&
                    response.data.isEnabled
                }
                onChange={(e) => changeconfigSelectFields(e)}
                onBlur={(e) => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                }}
              >
                {Object.keys(fields.data).map(
                    (obj) => {
                      return <Option key={obj}>{obj}</Option>;
                    }
                  )}
              </Field>
```

> top of the class I Add below method

```
const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the validation of a specific field by passing `disableValidation` array with field names in your form configuration object. Then you can check if this array contains the field name and if it doesn't provide the field with validation functions.

I suppose an example would demonstrate this best: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kf7WYdGZtEypx080L99